# Retrieve a record's created_by field to a passed in month and year in Rails3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

Im trying to make a side bar for my blog archive that lists out all the months for my blog entries, so when you click on a link such as "June 2007" all the blogs from June 07 are loaded.
Heres my link_to

```
<%= link_to month.first.strftime("%B %Y"), blog_archive_month_path(month.first.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) %>
```

month.first is a record I pulled up. Should my controller look something like this?:

```
@blog_posts = BlogPost.where(:created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") => params[:date]).(:select => "title, id, slug, created_at", :order => "created_at DESC")
```

I was hoping I could convert the records' created_by field to a format I could pass in an match but I get an undefined method erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I agree with what Dan Croak is saying (+1). The only mistake in his answer is that `.to_date` throws an error if there is not a complete date string in `params[:date]` (like in his example). So my suggestion would be:

View:

```
<%= link_to month.first.strftime("%B %Y"), blog_archive_month_path(month.first.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) %>
```

Controller:

```
@blog_posts = BlogPost.
  where(:created_at => params[:date].to_date.beginning_of_month..params[:date].to_date.end_of_month).
  order("created_at desc")
```

The problem with your original code is that you are trying to call `strftime` on `:created_at`, which is not possible.

Or if you don't like a full date in your URL, you could do this:

```
<%= link_to month.first.strftime("%B %Y"), blog_archive_month_path(month.first.strftime("%Y-%m")) %>
```

And:

```
@blog_posts = BlogPost.
  where(:created_at => "#{params[:date]}-01".to_date.beginning_of_month.."#{params[:date]}-01".to_date.end_of_month).
  order("created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

Bring the link down to just year-month:

```
<%= link_to month.first.strftime("%B %Y"), blog_archive_month_path(:date => month.first.strftime("%Y-%m")) %>
```

Then, use the range syntax to get a SQL BETWEEN:

```
@blog_posts = BlogPost.
              where(:created_at => (params[:date].to_date..(params[:date].to_date + 1.month))).
              order("created_at desc")
```

Comment: Doh yea I meant to just pass in the year-month (mustve copy pasta'd) bit I get an undefined method on teh .to_date

Comment: How about if you edit the path to be blog_archive_month_path(:date => month.first.strftime("%Y-%m"))

Comment: @rugbert - `to_date` only works if the string contains a full date: you also need the day. Other than that I suggest using `beginning_of_month` and `end_of_month`. E.g.: `'2011-6-7'.to_date.beginning_of_month => Wed, 01 Jun 2011`.

Comment: @mischa - if I understand correctly, my controller should look like this:` **@blog_posts = BlogPost.where(:created_by.to_date.beginning_of_month => params[:date]).(:select => "title, id, slug, created_at", :order => "created_at DESC")** `

Well the problem is that I cant run any methods of the :created_by field in the controller

Comment: @rugbert - No, that's not what I meant. I will add an answer myself, because it's difficult to show the code in a comment.